# Calculating observed values from a coin-toss simulation in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, probability, coin-flipping

I have a dataframe which was compiled by running a simulation on a two-coin toss 1000 times.

I.e. there is two-coins thrown in each test. The test is repeated 1000 times.

Heads are 1, tail are 2.

Here is a preview of the dataframe.

```
       X1   X2
1   X1  2   1
2   X2  1   1
3   X3  1   2
4   X4  1   1
5   X5  1   1
6   X6  1   2
7   X7  1   2
8   X8  1   2
9   X9  1   1
10  X10 2   1
```

It contains 1000 obs of 2 variables.

I want to calculated the observed values for the following conditions:

1. The chance that both coins are heads

   ```
   sum(df.sim$X1 == 1 & df.sim$X2 == 1)/1000
   ```
2. The chance that both coins will be different

   ```
   sum(df.sim$X1 == 2 & df.sim$X2 == 1)/1000
   ```
3. The chance that at-least one coin will be heads.

   not sure...

How would I calculate the observed value for the condition number 3, and did I calculate the observed values correctly for the first two conditions.

I know that the values I should get for the conditions are as follows

1. 25%
2. 50%
3. 75%

Comment: Before you get to n.3, number 2 is incomplete

Comment: Could you explain further.

Comment: You only calculate the pct that the first coin is tails and second is heads. What about the first coin Heads and the second tails? That satisfies the condition and should be included. Instead of two statements, you can just test x1 not equal to x2.

Comment: Would...
"sum((df.sim$X1 == 2 & df.sim$X2 == 1) + sum(df.sim$X1 == 1 & df.sim$X2 == 2))/1000"

achieve this condition?

Comment: You used `sum` and the `+` sign. It'll work, but using both is unnecessary `sum((1) + sum(1)) [1] 2`

Comment: Another way of saying that the coins are different is that the coins are not the same. Try writing X1 is not equal to X2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, your approach doesn't consider when the first coin is heads and the second tails. But this approach would work:

```
mean(df.sim$X1 != df.sim$X2)
```

For #3, you could do the same thing as #1, but use `|` (OR) rather than `&` (AND).

```
mean(df.sim$X1 == 1 | df.sim$X2 == 1)
```

Note that using `mean` rather than `sum` allows you to skip the `/1000` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df <- df.sim[X1] + df.sim[X2]
length(df[df == 3])/1000
```